# How to pass multiple lines to a parameter without a for loop?

Tags: shell-script, shell, nmap

I have the following command to process nmap output that contains a list of ips that I've been asked to scan:

```
cat ping-sweep.txt | grep "report for" | cut -d " " -f5
```

This is providing me a list of only the ip's (one per line) which I'd then like to scan for web servers.

I can scan an individual host with the following:

```
nmap -v -p 80,443,8080 10.1.1.1
```

I'd like to perform this scan on every ip in my list however piping it into nmap doesn't appear to work. Do I need to create a bash script with a `foreach` to do this or is there something simple that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be trying to use Nmap in the way it was designed. Since Nmap performs host discovery ("ping sweep") prior to each port scan, you can do both steps at once with this simple command:

```
nmap -p 80,443,8080 [TARGETS]
```

If you really do need to perform the host discovery separately from the port scan, then use Nmap's robust machine-readable output options like [XML](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html) or [Grepable](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) output. For older versions of Nmap, the easiest way would be to do the host discovery and save the Grepable output like so:

```
nmap -sn [TARGETS] -oG ping-sweep.gnmap
```

Then you can extract the IP addresses easily with awk:

```
awk '/Status: Up/{print $2}' ping-sweep.gnmap > targets.txt
```

and import them directly to Nmap:

```
nmap -p 80,443,8080 -iL targets.txt
```

Alternatively, with Nmap 7.00 or newer, you can use the XML output format saved with `-oX ping-sweep.xml` and the [targets-xml](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/targets-xml.html) NSE script:

```
nmap -p 80,443,8080 --script targets-xml --script-args newtargets,iX=ping-sweep.xml
```

With any of these options, if your host discovery scan is recent enough, you can add the `-Pn` option to skip the host discovery phase of the port scan. This saves you a tiny bit of scan speed, since you ought to be able to count on those same hosts still being up.

What you **really should not do** is any solution involving loops or `xargs`, since these will end up launching a separate Nmap instance for each target. This is wasteful and unnecessary, since each instance will have to duplicate the work of loading data files and sending timing probes to monitor network capacity, and the separate instances will be competing with each other for network resources instead of cooperating. Also, you'll have to recombine their separate outputs in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can give `nmap` all the addresses to scan as parameters, like this:

```
nmap -v -p 80,443,8080 $(grep "report for" ping-sweep.txt | cut -d" " -f5)
```

This runs `grep` on your file (no need for `cat`), then filters `grep`'s output through `cut`, and the result of that is used to build the `nmap` command line. This is known as [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

There are loops in the shell, and you could use one, in various ways:

```
grep "report for" ping-sweep.txt | cut -d" " -f5 | while read ip; do
    nmap -v -p 80,443,8080 "${ip}"
done
```

or

```
for ip in $(grep "report for" ping-sweep.txt | cut -d" " -f5); do
    nmap -v -p 80,443,8080 "${ip}"
done
```

Both of these will run `nmap` with one address at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Most generically, you can use `xargs` to pass each line as command-line argument to a command, like this:

```
cat ping-sweep.txt | grep "report for" | cut -d " " -f5 | xargs -I'{}' nmap -v -p 80,443,8080 '{}'
```